# setTimeout vs. Event binding/unbinding; what's more efficient?

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a situation where I need to use jQuery's `$.fn.one()` function for a click event, but I don't want it to apply to the next occurrence of the event (like it usually does), I want it to apply to the occurrence immediately after that, and then unbind itself (like `.one()` normally does).

The reason I don't want `.one()` to apply to the first occurrence is because I'm binding to the `document` from an event handler invoked earlier in the bubbling phase, so the first time it gets to `document` it'll be part of the same event. I want to know when the very next click event occurs.

**Note:** I do not want to use `.stopPropagation()` because it will potentially break other parts of my app.

Here are the two options I've come up with, though it seems like there must be a more elegant solution.

**The double bind method:**

```
$(document).one('click', function() {
  $(document).one('click', callback);
});
```

**The setTimeout method:**

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $(document).one('click', callback);
}, 1);
```

Both methods work just fine, but here's my question. I have no idea what the performance implications are for either setTimeout or frequent event binding and unbinding. If anyone knows, I'd love to hear it. But more importantly, I'd like some suggestions on how to measure this stuff myself for future situations like this.

I love sites like http://jsperf.com, but I don't know if it would really be helpful for measuring stuff like this.

And obviously, if someone sees a much better solution, I've love to hear it.

Comment: Tipically you'd bind delegated events to the closest parent element. I can't see many cases where binding to `document` is necessary if you have some clean markup.

Comment: You're correct about that when using `$.fn.delegate()`, but that's not what I'm talking about. I'm binding to `document` because I need to catch a click event that occurs anywhere on the page.

Comment: You could bind to `body` or create an absolute positioned overlay `div` and bind to that with `on()`. Without your actual html is hard to tell how to optimize.

Comment: It's going to be slightly more performant to do that, elclanrs, but once you're that high up in the tree, you're not losing much by just binding the listener to document. I definitely would't create a new div unless it was absolutely necessary.

Comment: I prefer the double-bind method because it reflects your actual intent. Using `setTimeout()` is more of a kludge.

Comment: Binding to body isn't an option because sometimes the body doesn't cover the whole page. Also, my HTML structure is irrelevant as this is for a plugin, so it should work with any markup you can throw at it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the double-bind method quite elegant - I think it accurately reflects your actual intent, and it only takes two lines of code.

But another approach is rather than using `.one()` you could use `.on()` and update the event object associated with the first event, adding a flag so that the callback will ignore the first time it is called:

```
function oneCallback(e) {
    if (e.originalEvent.firstTimeIn)
        return;

    alert("This is the one after the current event");
    $(document).off("click", oneCallback);
}

$("div.source").click(function(e) {
    e.originalEvent.firstTimeIn = true;
    $(document).on("click", oneCallback);   
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q5LG4/

EDIT: To address your concerns about not modifying the `event` object (or any object you don't own) you could store a firstTime flag in a closure. Here's a rather dodgy `.oneAfterThis()` plugin that takes that approach:

```
jQuery.fn.oneAfterThis = function(eventName, callback) {
    this.each(function() {
        var first = true;
        function cb() {
            if(first){
                first = false;
                return;
            }
            callback.apply(this,[].slice.call(arguments));
            $(this).off(eventName,cb);
        }
        $(this).on(eventName, cb);
    });
};

$(someseletor).oneAfterThis("click", function() { ... });
```

I'm sure that could've done that more elegantly (perhaps I should've bothered to look at how jQuery implements `.one()`), but I just wanted to whip something up quickly as a proof of concept.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/q5LG4/1/

Comment: I actually had originally started using such a solution, but I started to feel weird about modifying the actual event object, since it's globally accessible to everyone else. This kept jabbing at my mind: http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/03/02/maintainable-javascript-dont-modify-objects-you-down-own/

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about modifying the event object. The fact that you're using jQuery in the first place means you're not using the native event object (hence the need to add the property to `event.originalEvent`). If the property name you add is prefixed with your plugin name it should be pretty safe. But I've updated my answer with an alternative method...

Comment: thanks, I put together a jsperf (http://jsperf.com/double-binding-vs-oneafterthis) to test your plugin vs. the double bind method, and it looks like there's no clear winner, so I'll probably just stick with the double bind method since it's simpler. But after thinking about it more, I definitely agree that using setTimeout is kludgy.